# Pypdf2 append not importing bookmarks of pdfs correctly

Tags: python, pypdf, bookmarks, tableofcontents

pdf1

bookmark ---> points to page

```
 a --> 10
 b --> 20
 c --> 30
```

pdf2

bookmark ---> points to page

```
 q --> 5
 r --> 6
```

**combined pdf** bookmarks not pointing to correct page relative to new combined file

bookmark ---> points to page

```
 a --> 10
 b --> 20
 c --> 30
 q --> 5
 r --> 6
```

what I am trying to achieve is

```
 a --> 10
 b --> 20
 c --> 30
 q --> 35
 r --> 36
```

The generated bookmark in the combined pdf is **not pointing to the correct page relative to new combined file**

```
import os
import PyPDF2

root_directory = r'E:\ppp\ro'

def combine_pdfs(max_pages):
    combined_pdfs = []
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_directory, topdown=True):
        if 'combined' in dirnames:
            combined_directory = os.path.join(dirpath, 'combined')
            pdf_files = [os.path.join(combined_directory, filename) for filename in os.listdir(combined_directory) if filename.endswith('.pdf')]
            pdf_files.sort(reverse=True)

            pdf_index = 0
            while pdf_files:
                pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
                total_pages = 0

                while pdf_index < len(pdf_files):
                    pdf_file = pdf_files[pdf_index]
                    print(pdf_file)
                    with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as input_file:
                        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(input_file)
                        num_pages =  len(pdf_reader.pages)
                        if total_pages + num_pages <= max_pages:
                            pdf_writer.append(pdf_file)
                            total_pages += num_pages
                            pdf_index += 1
                        else:
                            break

                output_path = os.path.join(combined_directory, f'combinedpdf.pdf')
                with open(output_path, 'wb') as output_file:
                    pdf_writer.write(output_file)
                if pdf_index >= len(pdf_files):
                    break

combine_pdfs(max_pages=200)
```

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf

Comment: Did you try to find the issue in the project itself?

Comment: Have tried numerous way to append pdf, such as using merger.append , writer.append
each appends,also adds bookmarks from the original files,but they dont point to correct pagenumber based on combined pdf file.

Comment: Is there any workaround to modify the outline list  /page to increment before appending

Comment: K J,That was insightful,what i am stuck is how do i increment the outline list and add to the final combined pdf,tried several logic but couldn't achieve it.